# How to read last input to Scanner instance again?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How can I get the console scanner to use last input again?
    if I have something like `y=scanner.nextInt();`
and I want my next use of the scanner to use the same input from the previous line, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

> I want my next use of the scanner to use the same input from the previous line, how would I do that?

There is no way to make a `Scanner` do that.  The Scanner API does not provide any methods for backtracking to a point before the last successful read operation.  And trying to do this by "seeking" the underlying stream is unlikely to work either because of the scanner's internal buffering.

The best I can think of as a general solution is this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( ... )
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
    // read tokens from lineScanner
    // to "reset" to the start of the line, discard lineScanner
    // and create a new one.
}
```

Another approach might be just to save the things that you scanned, and do the resetting at a higher level.  But that doesn't work if you need to rescan the line *differently*; e.g. using `nextInt()` calls instead of `next()` calls.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the console scanner to use last input again?

Don't. Save the last input in a variable or a collection and access it that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
    y=scanner.nextInt();//user inputs 5
     y=5;// You can reuse y
     x=y;// assign same input to another value
```